# Azure Tags issue

Tags: powershell, tags

I am picking information from CSV file and i have mentioned tags like @{"R"="red";"B"="Blue"}.
when i am assigning tags value to variable , it is printing on same format but while adding tags to vm i am getting below error ,

```
Set-AzResource : Cannot bind parameter 'Tag'. Cannot convert the "System.Collections.Hashtable" value of type "System.String" to



$tags| convertfrom-stringdata
```

but the problem is after running add tag command for Vm , it is adding tag like below 
@{"r : ="red";"B"="Blue"}

**How can i add both tag as a separate like 
r:red    b:blue**

```
$rss = Import-csv "C:\abc\VijayGupta\Desktop\Vm_build_azure.csv"
$tag = $rss.vmtags 
$tags = $tag | ConvertFrom-StringData
$vms=Get-AzResource -Name abc -ResourceGroupName Southindia
Set-AzResource -ResourceId $vms.Id -Tag $tags -Force
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand the question, in your CSV file, there is a column called `vmtags`. The values in that column are strings in the form of `@{"R"="red";"B"="Blue"}`.

The `Get-AzResource` cmdlet wants a Hashtable object for its `-Tags` parameter. I think you took the description MS gives: *Key-value pairs in the form of a hash table. For example: @{key0="value0";key1=$null;key2="value2"}* a bit too literal there and now you need to create an actual Hashtable **object** from its string representation.

To create a Hashtable from a string like that you can use

```
# create a scriptblock using the string
$scriptBlock = [scriptblock]::Create('@{"R"="red";"B"="Blue"')
# execute it to create the hashtable
$tags = (& $scriptBlock)
```

**$tags** is now a Hashtable containing

> ```
> Name                           Value
> ----                           -----
> R                              red
> B                              Blue
> ```

If you need to create a Hashtable from multiple strings, do something like

```
$vmtags = '@{"R"="red";"B"="Blue"}', '@{"G"="green";"A"="Alpha"}'

# first loop creates the hashtables from the individual strings
$arr = $vmtags | ForEach-Object {
    $scriptBlock = [scriptblock]::Create($_)
    & $scriptBlock
}

# the second loop merges all Hashtables in the array into one
$tags = @{}
$arr | ForEach-Object {
    foreach ($key in $_.Keys) {
        $tags[$key] = $_.$key
    }
}
```

**$tags** is now a Hashtable containing

> ```
> Name                           Value
> ----                           -----
> R                              red
> B                              Blue
> A                              Alpha
> G                              green
> ```

Comment: thanks a lot for your above advise , will try to follow given steps